# Checkout from a windows share

Tags: windows, svn, svn-checkout, windows-share

I have created a repository in a shared folder. Usually I simply mapped a drive and checked out the repository using a file URL:

```
svn checkout file:///T:\MyRepository .
where T: is \\mySharedFolder
```

Is there some way how to specify in a url directly a path of a shared folder?

Something like:

```
svn checkout \\mySharedFolder\MyRepository .
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `file://mySharedFolder/MyRepository`

Comment: I am using tortoisesvn which is on windows and when I try to supply the a repository url as you have suggested (file:///\\mySharedFolder\MyRepository) I receive an error: *Unable to open an ra_local session to url*. Which client do you use where such syntax is accepted?